# How to apologize to my boss for saying something that offended her?

Tags: work-environment, healthcare-industry

I work in private care. My boss and I have a great relationship. I care for her mother. Today her mother was ignoring me and I made a joke, one my boss has and I've made multiple times, about when she ignores me it's like talking to a wall. My boss heard me and told me I was completely out of line and told me to pack my stuff and leave. I obviously offended her and I'm not sure how to go about an apology.

Comment: So, your boss has heard this in the past and not reacted this way? Also, by pack and leave, were you fired?

Comment: She never told me of I was fired or not. I'm scheduled to work in the morning yet unsure if she wants me to come in.

Comment: If you do apologize make sure you seem sincere, if not you may be better off not apologizing at all.

Comment: For clarification, it sounds like your boss has *also* made that same joke in the past, as well as you. Is that correct? Also, is this a joke you told to your boss, or did you say it to someone else and your boss overheard you? As written either seems possible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a believer in false platitudes.  If you're sorry, show it through your actions.  Understand that what you did may be unprofessional and stop making jokes at your patient's expense.

To me, it doesn't sound like you're actually sorry. You've made this joke multiple times with your boss, but only now that you've had a negative reaction you feel bad about doing so.

Don't be disparaging towards others and you'll find you'll have little to apologize for.

Answer (score 3):

1. Apologize, in person, with sincerity.
2. Understand that no matter how friendly you are with your clients... and your bosses, that they aren't your friends. Always act accordingly.

I never get so friendly with either that I let my words or actions cross the boundaries of professionalism. One day they're your friend and the next day they're having a bad day and call you out because you said or did something because you got too friendly, too familiar, or too comfortable.